# How to circumvent the Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?) when saving large Tidymodels workflowsets tibble

Tags: r, machine-learning, modeling, dataset

I have a question related to the methodology of working with tibbles and tidymodels workflowsets.

I have a large number of models fitted and tuned using several recipe pre-processing steps/feature engineering. The result is a LARGE tibble with my tuned models (50 rows, where each row is the unique combination of model x pre-processing).

```
[1] "workflow_set" "tbl_df"       "tbl"          "data.frame"
```

Because I don't want to run the whole workflowset tuning again I save the result in an `.RDS` file format, with no problem. However when I try to load the `.RDS` file into my environment again my `RStudio` complains about memory being exhausted

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

So my question is: Is there a way to save and/or load a large `tibble` that can avoid this problem?

I have already tried the following that gives me the same error: (`Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`):

- Unnesting the workflow_set tibble by using `unnest()`
- I have also tried saving and loading as an `.Rdata` file

**Disclaimer:**
I am aware that I don't have a reprex, but my question is not directly related to code – hence also why I did ask it here on Cross-Validated and not Stack Overflow. Of course if you really find it difficult to help out, don't hesitate to contact me and I will see what I can do to add specific code to this question.